# Is it possible to have an api call another api, having them both in same application?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a python application running on my localhost:3978. Is it possible to make an api call to **http://localhost:3978/api/users** from **http://localhost:3978/api/accounts**?

```
@routes.get("/api/accounts")
async def accounts(request):    
    api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3978/api/users"    
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    return json_response(data=respone.json())

@routes.get("/api/users")
async def users(request):
    pass
```

Comment: You can explicitly redirect to any other api using`` return redirect(url_for(func_name) ) `` else separate the controller logic from route and just call the controller function for that route.

Comment: In aiohttp, I know that `aiohttp.web.HTTPFound('\someendpoint')` redirects to the given endpoint and completes the execution, but I want it to come to the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `url_path_for()` to feed in `RedirectResponse` of `starlette.responses` as stated [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/199#issuecomment-492541834). For example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/a")
async def a():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.get('/b')
async def b():
    url = app.url_path_for("a")
    response = RedirectResponse(url=url)
    return response
```